# Waiting for multiple user entries before sending API request

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I am currently developing an application in flutter where the user types a text, which I send through an API POST request. I'm currently able to get the text and send it and get a response, it works fine.

The thing is, I want to allow the user to write multiple messages successively, before sending the request to the API; something like that:

- user types message
- user presses send message
- wait to see if user is typing another message before sending the API request
- if user is typing, wait till he presses send, and make one API request with both messages

I don't know if that is possible to do in flutter. I read about debounce() method of different packages but i saw that it works witha delay, does it also work with checking for typing conditions?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The crux of my question of your question... is how long should the code wait? For instance, if the user _is_ typing another message afterwards, how long should we wait before they add that message before we send the API request? That's where debounce comes in.

Comment: I was going to say something very similar to @DrSatan1. You can set up a delay using a `Timer` & use a `TextEditingController` to monitor the textfield's usage.

Comment: @DrSatan1 & EliFront thanks for answering. So supposing I have a delay of 3 seconds, would I be using debounce() with a that delay, but how would I be checking the texteditingcontroller for him typing while that delay is happening?

Comment: Basically like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52930197/2375907

Add any additional logic you may want inside of the `_onSearchChanged` (or equivalent) function.

So to understand whether the user is typing, simply check whether the timer is still active! (Hope I understood correctly)

Comment: Also, perhaps look at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53146151/2375907